# CKEditor: Executing toolbar buttons from javascript

Tags: qt, ckeditor

Here is my problem: I'm integrating CKEditor in a QT program. I want to create some functions in my program to execute some commands from the CKEditor toolbar. For example, I want a function "bold()" to apply that style to the selected text. This is what I have managed to do so far to accomplish this:

```
    void On_ActionBold_Triggered()
{
        this->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("var editor = CKEDITOR.currentInstance;"
                                                      "var style = new CKEDITOR.style( { element: 'strong', overrides: 'b' } );"
                                                      "if ( style.checkActive(editor.elementPath(), editor ) )"
                                                        "editor.removeStyle( style );"
                                                      "else if ( !style.checkActive(editor.elementPath(), editor ) )"
                                                        "editor.applyStyle( style );");
}
```

This uses the function "applyStyle()" from CKEditor. But I have to implement some conditionals to check if the selected text already has the style in order to apply or remove the style depending on the situation. With the "Bold" button, this is pretty straightforward. But with some other buttons, it will not be so straightforward, and I'm trying to avoid going over the trouble of re-implementing the functions for all the buttons. I wonder whether there is a more direct way to construct this function. Something like this:

```
     void On_ActionBold_Triggered()
{
        this->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("var editor = CKEDITOR.currentInstance;"
                                                        "editor.executeWhateverCommandIsAssociattedWithTheBoldButtonInToolbar();");
}
```

Is there any way to do this? I guess that another option would be to look in the source-code of CKEditor and simply copy and paste the implementation of the functions for the different buttons. But I still didn't manage to find the implementation of the functions for the different buttons in the source... Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**UPDATE**:

I end up finding the solution to the problem. Here is how I'm doing it now:

```
void CKEditor_Bold(){this->page()->mainFrame()->evaluateJavaScript("CKEDITOR.currentInstance.execCommand('bold');");}
```